# How can style be applied to tag helpers in a ASP.NET Core Razor view?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

In a standard ASP.NET Core application say I have the following:

Model.cs

```
[Display(Name = "Foo")]
public string Foo { get;set; }

[Display(Name = "Bar")]
public string Bar{ get;set; }
```

Index.cshtml

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label asp-for="Foo"></label><br />
                <label>@Model.Foo</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
                <label asp-for="Bar"></label><br />
                <label>@Model.Bar</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Within site.css I have tried both of the following

```
label.bluetext{
    color: #3064b8; 
}
```

and

```
.bluetext{
    color: #3064b8; 
}
```

while applying the style like so

`<label class="bluetext">@Model.Foo</label>`

but I can't seem to get this to work with Razor tag helpers.

Comment: Shouldn't your `Foo` or `Bar` equal `bluetext`?

Comment: What's wrong with adding `class="bluetext"` on each label generated by the tag helper like `<label asp-for="" class="bluetext" />`?

Comment: @DavidLiang Because one is dynamic from the model, the other is a label that will be on the form.  I want the text input by the user to be a different color.  For example, an actual form value will be Name & Email.  So the labels will be "Name" and "Email" while the value will be entered by the user.  That value will be stored in the model and I want that to be blue on the next page, not the label denoting what field is being displayed.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Yes, later in the question I demonstrate how I attempted to use it as `<label class="bluetext">@Model.Foo</label>`

Comment: @Mkalafut: I still don't get what you meant by that. `<label asp-for="Foo"></label>` will generate a label with the property's display name annotation.  `<label>@Model.Foo</label>` will generate a label with the property value. Your code shows labels only. I don't see any input controlls.

Comment: @DavidLiang You're correct.  We're saying the same thing.  When I apply the class, the text is still not blue.  `<label class="bluetext">@Model.Foo</label>` still displays the default standard text color.

Comment: @Mkalafut: that has nothing to do with tag helpers since the label `<label class="bluetext">@Model.Foo</label>` is not generated by that. There must be something with your CSS files. I bet some other styles override this .bluetext style. Check the orders of how you load those CSS files. At least show us the screenshot on the label with the developer tool turned on.

Comment: @DavidLiang Came in this morning after restarting my PC and now it's working.  This is embarrassing.  Must have been a cache issue or something.  Style applied as expected and I changed nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could press F12 to open DevTools and check whether the custom styles are applied successfully in the Sources Tab -> css folder -> site.css.

[image]

If not, clear cache and reload the page.

Try to use `asp-append-version="true"` in your reference. It will append a version as a query string parameter which changes when the file is modified.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
```

You could also direcly add styles in Index.cshtml to make it

```
<style>
   label.bluetext {
      color:#3064b8;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Was probably a cache issue.  I came in this morning and did exactly what you proposed.  Loaded up the solution, immediately saw the blue text on the screen and the style applied to my label.  Thanks.